# Object Literal May Only Specify Known Properties

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on learning how to create an Angular Firebase Chat following a youtube video series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-j0LVc-zLh0

Here, I'm working on a chat service (chat.service.ts) that is as follows:

```
import {
    Injectable
} from '@angular/core';
import {
    AngularFireList, AngularFireDatabase
} from 'angularfire2/database';
import {
    AngularFireAuth
} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {
    Observable
} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {
    ChatMessage
} from '../models/chat-message.model';
import {
    AuthService
} from '../services/auth.service';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';



@Injectable()
export class ChatService {
    user: any;
    chatMessages: AngularFireList < ChatMessage[]> ;
    chatMessage: ChatMessage;
    userName: Observable<string>;

    constructor(
        private db: AngularFireDatabase,
        private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth
    ) {
        // this.angularFireAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
        //  if (auth !== undefined && auth !== null) {
        //      this.user = auth;
        //  }
        // })

    }

    sendMessage(msg: string) {
        const timestamp = this.getTimestamp();
        // const email = this.user.email;
        const email = "ex@ex.com";
        this.chatMessages = this.getMessages();
        this.chatMessages.push({
            message: msg,
            timeSent: timestamp,
            userName: this.userName,
            email: email
        }); 
    }

    getMessages(): AngularFireList<ChatMessage[]> {
        return this.db.list('messages', ref => ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(25)
        // console.log("test ok")
    )};

    getTimestamp() {
        const now = new Date();
        const date = now.getUTCFullYear() + '/' + (now.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '/' + now.getUTCDate();
        const time = now.getUTCHours() + ':' + (now.getUTCMinutes()) + ':' + now.getUTCSeconds();
        return (date + ' ' + time);
    }
}
```

In the sendMessage function, when I try to push the message I get into ChatMessages[], the `message: msg` line is marked as an error, and I get the following error message in my terminal.

> ERROR in src/app/services/chat.service.ts(48,4): error TS2345:
>   Argument of type '{ message: string; timeSent: string; userName:
>   Observable; email: string; }' is not assignable to parameter
>   of type 'ChatMessage[]'.   Object literal may only specify known
>   properties, and 'message' does not exist in type 'ChatMessage[]'.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Subscribe your observable and then push

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need brackets after ChatMessage.

```
 getMessages(): AngularFireList<ChatMessage> {
        return this.db.list('messages', ref => ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(25)
        // console.log("test ok")
    )};
```

If after this it still doesnot work then subscribe to your username before pushing.

```
this.chatMessages.push({
            message: msg,
            timeSent: timestamp,
            userName: this.userName,----subscribe it
            email: email
        });
```